# Finding specific solutions to trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

Find x if it is between -90 and 0 degrees and

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{\sin(x)} + \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = 4$$

I think I got the solution but I don't know how to close it out

= $$\sin(x) + \sqrt3\cos(x) = 4\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

By R-method and double angle

=$$ 2\sin(x+60) = 2sin(2x)$$

= $$\sin(x+60) = \sin(2x)$$

but I keep on getting confused on how to solve this such that it is inside a specific bound, is there a formula or something, especially if there are variables on each side.

Comment: Do you know how to solve an equation in the form
$$
\sin{x}=\sin{y}
$$
? It has a well-known solution ... Hint: it has infinitely many solutions

Comment: The only solution is $x=-4\pi /9$.

Answer (score 1):

I also like to see it in the following way. Recall cosine and sine are abscissa and ordinate of a point on the circle of radius $1$ centered in the origin. Thus you can rethink of your problem, as finding the intersection points between the line
$$\lambda : \frac{\sqrt 3}{Y} + \frac{1}{X} = 4$$
and the circumference
$$\gamma : X^2 + Y^2 = 1.$$

[image]

From the graph you readly see that the solutions are actually four. Let us find them trigonometrically.

Your final equation 
$$\sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \sin 2x$$ 
has the following sets of solutions.

First set is
$$x + \frac{\pi}{3} = 2x + 2k \pi$$
yielding
$$x = \frac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi,$$
(red dot in the Figure) and second set is
$$x + \frac{\pi}{3} = \pi - 2x + 2k\pi,$$
which gives
$$x = -\frac{\pi}{9} + k \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
(blue dots in the Figure).
The one you are interested in is of course in the fourth quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer for the original question. For the edited question the answer is similar and I leave it to you to make appropriate changes)
. Note that $|(x+\pi /3)- 2x| \leq \pi /3+\pi /2 =\pi$. Hence the only possibilites are $x+\pi /3=2x$ and $x+\pi /3=\pi - 2x$. This gives the solutions $x=\pi /3$ and $x=2\pi /9$.

Comment: sorry, typo, it should  -90

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-From your deduction $$\sin(x+60) = \sin(2x)\iff2\cos\left(\dfrac{3x+60}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{60-x}{2}\right)=0$$ Then because of $-90\le x\le 0$ you have the only solution $x=-\dfrac{4\pi}{9} (=-80^{\circ})$